# Is capitalisation of 'Yo' not important?

Tags: gramática

In English,  it is necessary to capitalize 'I' no matter where it lies in the sentence.

I am curious to know if this rule applies to **Yo** in Spanish.

Comment: Not only not necessary, but not correct.

Comment: I always wondered why "I" is capitalized in English.

Comment: @Jojo: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/7988/9983

Answer (score 11):

No, the rule does not apply in Spanish.

The capitalization is only required at the beginning of the sentence, as any other word (except for names, of course).

You can write: "No es mayor que yo" (he is not older than I am).

Comment: You can, no. You *must* write it in lowercase.

Comment: By the way, mayor, although it also means "más grande", when refering to people means "de más edad". At least, that's how it's used in Spain. I've never heard mayor as "más alto", when it's about people.